# Jackson JsonParser is allowing (parsing) requests which don't have double quotes

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jsonparser

I am working with Jackson JsonParser to parse requests. I am trying to develop some apis in java and I encountered a problem with Jackson JsonParser. The problem is when anyone try to request my api with **unquoted field values** it is allowing it instead of rejecting. I know this is a kind of feature but it is giving me trouble with my project.

So why exactly I want this?
I have a java class as below.

```
public class CartDetails {

@NotNull(errorCode = "invalid.productId", message = "Invalid product Id.")
@NotEmpty(errorCode = "invalid.productId", message = "Invalid product Id.")
@MaxLength(value = 13, errorCode = "invalid.productId", message = "Product Id exceeded max length.")
public String productId;

/* Some more fields */
}
```

So here Product Id is String. But right now all of our product Id is in numeric form. But we make it string for future purpose to categories this id with adding some prefix character like "LA-1234". Here If you pass Json request as below

```
{   
"productId": "123456",
}
```

Or

```
{   
"productId": 123456,
}
```

it will be accepted and ObjectMapper will map it with my CartDetails class. But when I put any other character like " - " in my **unquoted** field values then it will complain and If same request goes with **quoted** field values then it will accept it.

```
{   
"productId": "LA-123456",
}
```

Above request will work. but not the below one.

```
{   
"productId": LA-123456,
}
```

So I want this below request also not to work.

```
{   
"productId": 123456,
}
```

I want it to be strict type checked. It should not allow any requests for type String without double quotes. Because I don't want any of my api consumer to keep using my api without passing request without quotes and when I change productId from "1234" to "LA-1234" suddenly everything start complaining.

I searched about "**com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature**" and **org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature** but nothing seems to work for this. Is there any way I can solve this issue with field values? There are feature for field Names but not for field values.

So is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Jackson will coerce non-string values to string, i.e. numbers and the `true`, `false`, and `null` keywords. If you absolutely don't want that, even though it's valid json, then you need to register your own string deserializer. I'd say to accept it. If you've ***documented*** that your product id is a string, and the users try to store and handle it as a number, then that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: @Andreas I was not aware about custom string deserializer. Thanks for letting me know. I will try to look into it but it looks pretty difficult. I know this is not my problem but I was just trying to make my api better. Thanks for your response.